# Argparse nested subparsers

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, command-line-arguments, argparse

I would like to created nested `subparsers` using the python 3 library `argparse`. At the moment I am getting this error message when trying to implement a solution:

```
AttributeError: 'ArgumentParser' object has no attribute 'add_parser'
```

Here is the code that I am using:

```
def parse_args():
    """
    Parse and validate user command line.
    """
    # Top-level parser
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="foo"
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        "-foo",
        dest="foo",
        help="foo",
        required=True,
        type=str
    )

    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help')

    # Parser for the "payload" command
    parser_payload = subparsers.add_parser(
        "payload", 
        help="payload help"
    )

    parser_payload.add_argument(
        "-b",
        "--bar",
        dest="bar",
        help="bar",
        type=str
    )

    # Parser for the "payload->foobar" command
    parser_payload_foobar = parser_payload.add_parser(
        "foobar"
        help="foobar help"
    )

    parser_payload_foobar.add_argument(
        "-bf",
        "--barfoo",
        dest="barfoo",
        help="barfoo",
        type=str
    )

    return parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: Which version? Can you give the full traceback? Cut the function down a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you see a pattern here?

```
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help')
...
parser_payload = subparsers.add_parser(   # ok
...
parser_payload.add_parser(    # error
```

`parser` has a `add_subparsers` method.  A `subparsers` object (what ever that is) has a `add_parser` method.  The error message says that a `parser` does not have that method.

If you want to add subparsers to `parser_payload` you have to start with the `add_subparsers` method.

`argparse` is organized around classes, whether it's obvious from the documentation or not.  Each class has its defined methods.

I like to develop in an interactive environment in which I can examine the class and attributes of the objects as the get created.

Comment: Indeed, I was confused between parser and subparsers objects, I was not sure that what I wanted to achieve was possible, hence, my question. Thanks!

Comment: Nesting like this is possible, though I haven't seen it often.  Anything you can do with `parser` you can do with `parser_payload`.